# Generating invertible matrix with lines within a given set

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, random, combinatorics

Consider the set `options` given as below

```
n=2;m=3;
options = 
 Complement[
  DeleteDuplicates[
   Table[Table[
     Product[Tuples[
          Table[Tuples[{1, -1}, n], {m}]][[i]][[k]][[Tuples[
           Table[i, {i, 1, n}], m][[j]][[k]]]], {k, 1, m}], {j, 1, 
      Length[Tuples[Table[i, {i, 1, n}], m]]}], {i, 1, 
     Length[Tuples[Table[Tuples[{1, -1}, n], {m}]]]}]], 
  Union[Tuples[{1}, n^m], Tuples[{-1}, n^m]]]
```

I am looking for a way to generate a random $n^m\times n^m$($=8\times8$) invertible matrix with the vector $(1,...,1)$ as the first line and with vectors from `options` as the other lines.

With

```
prematarb = RandomChoice[options, n^m - 1];
matarb = Prepend[prematarb, Table[1, {n^m}]];
MatrixForm[matarb]
Det[matarb]
```

we can generate a matrix like I want and calculate its determinant. But to find one with non-null determinant, I had to run the code about 50 times. Is there a way to make the code automatically repeat until it finds one invertible matrix?

One observation is that the matrices generated through the code above, in general, have repeated lines. Is there a way to minimize these repetitions? Could I change the `SeedRandom` to achieve the aim in a faster way? I see that in the case $n=m=3$, it is far too hard to find the matrix I want generating randomly. The case above has `14=Length[options]` options to fill each line of a $7\times 8$ matrix. But in the case $n=m=3$, we have 126 options to fill each line of a $26\times27$ matrix, and still it is common to see repeated lines within the generated matrices. So if there is a way to make things faster (like modifying `SeedRandom` or using some way for don't taking lines that already was taken to fill the lines), it could be really handy.

**EDIT:** We can reduce the set `options` to the half of the size by removing the symmetric elements, this way:

```
options2=Table[Reverse[Sort[options]][[i]], {i, 1, Length[options]/2}]
```

Comment: If you are choosing values from a possible list and you don't want repeats you should look at `RandomSample[...]`. Also your code is very difficult to follow with all the nested functions, you might consider refactoring it at least for the sake of getting more feedback.

Comment: @N.J.Evans Thank you for the tip. `RandomSample` answer the second question. I put the full set `options` defined in the OP just to work exactly with the set I am interested in. But it could be another set o vectors from $\Bbb R^n$. I only want to find a way to repeat the action of generating a random matrix until it finds an invertible one.

Comment: The method `options2=Table[Reverse[Sort[options]][[i]],{i,1,Length[options]/2}]` (which is identical to `options2=Take[-options,Length[options]/2]`) eliminates half the valid solutions. See my new answer. I hope I clearly explained the symmetry in `options`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your method, here's a way to repeatedly generate a random matrix until the matrix is invertible. First, turn your matrix generation into a function so it's easy to call from two places.

**Edit**: Remove generation of `options` from `genmat` since `options` doesn't change unless `n` or `m` are changed. `ConstantArray` is faster than `Table` for making a list of 1s. These changes find solution matrices more quickly (see comments).

```
genmat[n_, m_] := Prepend[RandomChoice[options,n^m - 1],ConstantArray[1,n^m]]
```

Next, initialize `options`. Do this once for new values of `n` or `m`.

```
n = 2; m = 3;
options = 
  Complement[
   DeleteDuplicates[
    Table[Table[
      Product[Tuples[Table[Tuples[{1, -1}, n], {m}]][[i]][[k]][[
         Tuples[Table[i, {i, 1, n}], m][[j]][[k]]]], {k, 1, m}], {j, 
       1, Length[Tuples[Table[i, {i, 1, n}], m]]}],
       {i, 1, Length[Tuples[Table[Tuples[{1, -1}, n], {m}]]]}]], 
   Union[Tuples[{1}, n^m], Tuples[{-1}, n^m]]];
```

The following `While` command will run until the determinant of `matarb` is not zero. Run again to find another matrix.

```
matarb = genmat[n, m]; (*initialize matrix*)
i = 0; (*counter*)
While[
 Det[matarb] == 0, {matarb = genmat[n, m], i += 1}];
TableForm[{MatrixForm[matarb], Det[matarb], i}, 
 TableDirections -> Row]
```

The result is a matrix, its determinant, and the number of matrices tested before finding a solution.

## Eliminate singular matrices

Finding solution matrices is quicker if there are fewer singular cases to test. As Filburt says in his question, the `options` matrix is symmetrical in this sense: the top half is the reverse of the negative of the bottom half. The symmetry is easy to see for the n=2, m=3 case:

```
choices = Length[options]/2 (*half the number of rows in the options matrix*);

TableForm[{MatrixPlot[Take[options, choices]],
  MatrixPlot[Reverse[-Take[options, -choices]]]}, 
 TableHeadings -> {{"Top half", 
    "Negative of bottom half,\nReversed"}}, TableDirections -> Row]
```

[image: Comparison of top and bottom of options matrix]

There are 17,297,280 possible test matrices using the original method where 14 rows of `options` are randomly selected 7 rows at a time. More than 99% of them are singular.

To test symmetry for any `n` and `m`, simply:

```
Take[options,choices] == Reverse[-Take[options,-choices]]
```

> True

### - Case where n = 2, m = 3

Because the bottom half of `options` is the negative of the top half, every corresponding row from the top half and the reverse of the bottom half of `options` results in a singular matrix. For example, if a test run selects rows 1, 3, 5, and 7 from the top half, only rows 2, 4, 6 from the bottom half will **not** result in a singular matrix.

Because of the symmetry in the `options` matrix, only the top half is needed.

```
cols = n^m;
top = Take[options, choices];
```

**It's unnecessary to compute the bottom half** of `options`, because `options == Join[top, Reverse[-top]]`.

We can entirely eliminate singular test matrices by randomly choosing rows from `top` and the complement of the rows from `-top`. Note that `top` and `-top` are not singular.

Here's how to make a list of random rows to be selected from `top`:

```
tr = RandomSample[Range[1, choices], RandomInteger[choices]]
```

> {6, 1, 5, 4}

Given `tr` rows, these are the rows to select from `-top`:

```
Complement[Range[choices], tr]
```

> {2, 3, 7}

Then **every** random `matarb` matrix is **not** singular (all singular test cases are eliminated):

```
tr = RandomSample[Range[1,choices], RandomInteger[choices]];
Det[matarb = Prepend[
  Join[top[[tr, All]], -top[[Complement[Range[choices],tr]]]],
    ConstantArray[1, cols]]]
```

The number of non-singular matrices (13,700 for n=2, m=3) is:

$$
\sum _{k=0}^{n^m-1} p\left(n^m-1,k\right)
$$

where $p({n},{k})\text{=}\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$.

### - Case where n = 2, m = any

Everything about the n=2, m=3 case applies when `m` is any value. Every randomly chosen matrix is **not** singular.

### - Case where n is not 2, m = any

When `n` is not 2, the top and bottom halves of `options` are symmetrical in the same way as the n=2 case. Test this as before with:

```
Take[options, choices] == Reverse[-Take[options, -choices]]
```

However, although choosing complementary rows reduces the number of singular test matrices, [Monte Carlo](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/MonteCarloEstimateForPi/) testing is needed to eliminate the ones that remain. I haven't coded a way to exploit the symmetry in the `options` matrix when `n` is not 2, but the same complementary-rows technique will help. Meanwhile, this method using `While` will find solutions.

```
choices = Length[options]/2;
cols = n^m;
matarb = Prepend[options[[RandomSample[Range[1,choices],cols-1], All]], 
  ConstantArray[1, cols]];
While[Det[matarb] == 0, 
  matarb = Prepend[
    options[[RandomSample[Range[1,choices],cols-1], All]], 
    ConstantArray[1,cols]]];
Det[matarb]
```

Comment: beautiful answer :-)

Comment: Hey man, could you tell me what is the role of `i` in your code? What's the difference between your `While` and `While[
 Det[matarb] == 0, matarb = genmat[n, m]];` ? It is only to count the number of times the body of `While` was tested, right?

Comment: @Filburt Yes, `i` just a counter. Other than that, it's not needed. If you're looking for only a few of the solution matrices, this Monte Carlo approach is good enough. For more speed, compute the 14 rows just once, outside of the `genmat` function. It's not necessary to compute them every time `genmat` runs. If you need every solution matrix (I think there are 13,700 of them), there are better methods. Is this set of 14 (or `2(n^m -1)`) rows the only ones you need to test?

Comment: Yes, once you fix $m$ and $n$, the set `options` is fixed too and it is the only being tested. Other thing, the same goes for the parentheses, right? I mean, they are not necessary since I use `;` to separate the tests withing the body.

Comment: Sadly, there is no way to give another +1 :-)

Comment: @Filbert You're welcome. Your question and the problem is an interesting one. There's room for improvement for the n>2 cases, and for n=2 and m<4 cases, it's easy to generate every possible solution matrix using permutations of the rows selected from `top`... all better left to another question :-)

Comment: Happy to known that it is interesting to you. Unfortunately there are a computational problem that drives me hopeless. The true aim for these matrices are generate some interesting vectors in $\Bbb R^{n^m}$, by multiplication with vectors from another set. But this another set is too big for any computer to hold (ex: m=3,n=4), it's size is $2^{n^m}$. Again I can generate `p` arbitrary elements within these $2^{n^m}$ and look at the points generated with them and the previous matrix. But the size of `p` cannot be big enough, so the probability of getting something interesting is almost zero :-(

Comment: Do you think we change your code to eliminate the matrices that differ by switching the rows? For example, if some matrices have the same set of rows, you take only one of them. We can make it at the final using `DeleteDuplicatesBy[Sort]`, but I was looking for a way to do that while we obtain the matrices, this way we will be able compute cases like `m=3;n=3;` without running out of memory (the number $\sum p(n^m−1,k)$ is very very big).

Comment: None of the n-by-m `options` matrices have duplicate rows. When selecting rows for `matarb` no row is selected twice, so `matarb` never has duplicate rows. For the n=2 cases, every `matarb` is non-singular. For n>2, `matarb` may be degenerate, but not because of duplicate rows. The problem for n>2 is caused by the way `options` is computed. Columns, rather than rows, cause the degenerate results.

Comment: @Filburt The original `options` code can changed to use less memory and run more quickly which is important for n>2 or for large m. See my second answer.

Answer (score 2):

Filburt's question in a 2-parter... The first part was how to select rows from `options` without selecting the same row twice for each `matarb`. That's done by selecting rows using `RandomSample` and by *not* selecting corresponding rows from the top and bottom halves of `options`.

The second part is how to improve the code. This replacement code for computing the `options` matrix doesn't change the results, but it uses half the memory and it's significantly faster for larger values of `n` and `m`.

```
n = 2; m = 3;
cols = n^m;
(* n == 1 and m == 1 are special cases *)
ii = If[n == 1 || m == 1, 2^(n*m), 2^(n*m - 1)];
tbla = Tuples[ 
   Table[Tuples[{1, -1}, n], m]];
tblb = Tuples[
   Table[i, {i, 1, n}], m];
options = Complement[
   Table[Table[
     Product[tbla[[i]][[k]][[tblb[[j]][[k]]]], {k, 1, m}],
     {j, 1, cols}], {i, 1, ii}],
   Union[{ConstantArray[-1, cols]}, {ConstantArray[1, cols]}]];
```

Comments about changes:

- For readability, compute `cols = n^m`. The value is used several times.
- Replace `Length` with computed values.

It's clear that:

```
Length[Tuples[Table[i, {i, 1, n}], m]]}] == cols
```

for all `n` and `m`, so we can use `{j, 1, cols}`. Also:

```
Length[Tuples[Table[Tuples[{1, -1}, n], {m}]]] == 2^(n*m)
```

for all `n` and `m`, so we can use `{i, 1, ii}`, where `ii` is computed with `If[m == 1 || n == 1, 2^(n*m), 2^(n*m - 1)]`.

The `2^(n*m)` term grows quickly, so reducing it is useful. Notice that `ii` is `2^(n*m - 1)` for most values of `n` and `m`. This change uses half the memory, and makes the code run almost twice as fast. The `2^(n*m)` value produces duplicate rows that are removed by `Complement`, so the result is unchanged.

- `Tuples[Table[Tuples[{1, -1}, n], m]]` doesn't change inside `Product`. Compute its value once as `tbla`. Do the same for `tblb = Tuples[Table[i, {i, 1, n}], m]`. For the n=3, m=4 case, computing `options` runs more than 50 times faster.
- `Union[{ConstantArray[-1, cols]}, {ConstantArray[1, cols]}]` is a bit faster than `Union[Tuples[{1}, n^m], Tuples[{-1}, n^m]]`.

With these changes, the code is faster and uses less memory.

Comment: Thank you for the improvements. Happy to see you're interested. There are good knowledge in your answer, thanks for that. I am not a programmer and it's just my first month learning Mathematica. I am happy to see what the forums provided for me. 

About the algorithm, after all the improvements, the code for generating an arbitrary matrix with those constraints is good enough for me. Now I am looking for a way to generate all these matrices (for `m=n=3`), and I realize that for my purposes there is no need for taking `options` completely, only one half (eliminating symmetrics) is sufficient.

Comment: But this is for another question in the future.

Comment: @Filburt One more embarrassing fix for the second table -- I didn't see it last night (*sigh*) ... glad I could help.