# Is there a way to calculate this big set using the hard disk space and use it from there?

Tags: list-manipulation, memory

I aim to work with two sets, obtained through a function. One of these are:

```
n=3; m=3;
bigset=Take[Tuples[{1, -1}, n^m], 2^(n^m-1)];
```

(It calculates the set Tuples[{1, -1}, n^m] and takes the first half of it)

This set is easy to compute but hard to store (more than 100 GB, I think). I have only 8 GB of RAM. Every time I run this code, the computer freezes forever. Is there a way to calculate this big set using the hard disk space (taking no more than one night) and use it from there?

EDIT: The other set (called `matrixset`) can be obtained in the following way:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

m = 3;
n = 3;

Inm = Tuples[Table[i, {i, 1, n}], m];
extBn = Tuples[{1, -1}, n];
prodBn = Tuples[Table[extBn, {m}]];
w[i_, j_] := Product[prodBn[[i]][[k]][[Inm[[j]][[k]]]], {k, 1, m}];
Vnm = DeleteDuplicates[
   Table[Table[w[i, j], {j, 1, Length[Inm]}], {i, 1, Length[prodBn]}]];
remove = Union[Tuples[{1}, n^m], Tuples[{-1}, n^m]];
V0 = {{Vnm[[1]]}};
S = Complement[Vnm, remove]; "";
S0 = Table[{S[[i]]}, {i, 1, Length[S]}]; ""; Clear[S];
f[S0_, {i_, V0_}] := Module[{S1, S2}, S1 = Join @@@ Tuples[{S0, V0}];
  S2 = Pick[DeleteDuplicatesBy[Sort]@S1, 
    MatrixRank[#] == i & /@ DeleteDuplicatesBy[Sort]@S1];
  {i + 1, S2}]
matrixset = Last@Nest[f[S0, #] &, {2, V0}, n^m - 1]; ""; Clear[S0];
```

The set consist of all invertible matrices $27\times 27$ that have the unit vector $(1,...,1)$ as the last line and vectors from the set $Vnm$ as the other lines. The process remove those that differ by row-switching.

The set `S0` consists of 1-row matrices from $Vnm\backslash \{(1~\cdots~1), (-1~\cdots~-1)\}$. Here is how the Module work: (1) `Prepend` all vectors from `S0` to the 1-line matrix $(1~\cdots~1)$; (2) obtain `S1` by eliminating the matrices duplicated by row-switching and those with rank $< 2$; (3) `Prepend` all vectors from `S0` to all matrices from `S1`; (4) obtain `S2` by eliminating the matrices duplicated by row-switching and those with rank $< 3$; (5) and so on.....

Answer (score 5):

Observation: If you replace `Tuples[{1, -1}...` with `Tuples[{0, 1}...` you'll be generating the base-2 integer digits of the numbers 0 through `2^(n^m-1)-1`.

Therefore instead of generating the entire `bigset` you can simply realize that

```
bigset[[i]] == PadLeft[IntegerDigits[i - 1, 2], n^m] /. {0 -> 1, 1 -> -1}
```

or as J.M. points out, a much terser and performance-wise better variant of the expression above is

```
1 - 2 IntegerDigits[i - 1, 2, n^m]
```

Observations regarding memory consumption: you are in intermediate calculations generating a `2^27 * 27` array of integers (each of which are 64 bits in size). In principle, you could manage with 32 GB RAM or maybe slightly more. But since every 27-integer tuple is 216 bytes in size, when it could be represented by *a single integer* you are wasting memory by a factor of 27! Now my machine has also 8GB memory and generating `range = Range[0, 2^26 - 1];` is no problem whatsoever and consumes only 500-something MB of memory.

Comment: `1 - 2 IntegerDigits[i - 1, 2, n^m]` is shorter.

Comment: @J.M. and much faster in the long run, thanks.

Comment: Even with `{0,1}` instead of `{1,-1}`, I haven't enough RAM to hold it. The same for `PadLeft` if the objective is to store all $2^{26}$ elements

Comment: @Filburt the point is that *you don't have to hold it*. If you know in advance how to generate any given element, that should be enough in most cases. I believe, your question is an example of an XY problem. Perhaps you could show us, what you want to do with your two sets?

Comment: @LLlAMnYP The other set is a little bit complicated to obtain. Is a set of $27\times 27$ matrices, and I want multiply each element of the second set with the transpose of each element from the `bigset`. You are right, I realize that we don't have to store `bigset`. But maybe I will have no choice with the other one. The set is this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/157585/generating-invertible-matrix-with-lines-within-a-given-set

Comment: @LLlAMnYP The answer I get in that link didn't eliminated the matrices that differ from another by switching lines, hence that big number. The set is actually smaller. I will put a way to obtain it in the OP.

Comment: @Filburt I see. I *hope* there's some way to reduce the ridiculous size of your humongous matrix set. Running your code froze my kernel. To clarify, you want the result of multiplying each possible matrix by each possible vector?

Comment: @LLlAMnYP to reach the final aim, we can do this step by step: (1) take one vector and one matrix; (2) do some (very simple) computations (transpose and multiplying); (3) generate a few (possibly none) elements; (5) delete duplicates (there will be a lot) and store;
 (4) take another pair matrix-vector; (5) do the operations again, store results and delete duplicates and repeat....
There will be a lot of duplicates, the final set will be very small, but the calculus have to be done with each possible matrix and each possible vector, and I know this will take a while.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP You could run the code `m=3;n=2` (`matrixset` will have 128 elements), I assure you it will runs easily (but 8GB is not enought to run `m=2;n=3`). I hope we could calculate other cases using the hard disk space, taking a reasonable time. I give you +1 anyway.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP I realize that for my purposes, there is no need to take `Vnm` completely, we can, actually, remove the symmetrics elements. This way, you can take `S0 = {#} & /@ 
   Complement[Take[Reverse[Sort[Vnm]], Length[Vnm]/2],{ConstantArray[1, n^m]}];` and have the half of the options to fill the matrices. This way I was able to run `m=2;n=3` easily.

Comment: @fil I'll have a closer look at your problem on Monday